# Can not connect to NGINX with Docker-Compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I just had to tranfer my development enviroment to a new Mac and set up Docker on the new machine. I am using docker-compose to host a local wordpress with nginx. All container are starting, but the nginx container refuses to work. So I can't reach the site under localhost:8000

I have the same configuration on my old computer and it is running smoothly. Am I am missing something?

So, this is my dockerfile:

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/wordpress-mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./docker-runtime/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    image: wodby/wordpress-php
    environment:
      PHP_SITE_NAME: dev
      PHP_HOST_NAME: localhost:8000
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 0 
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: wodby/wordpress-nginx
    environment:
      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: localhost
      NGINX_UPSTREAM_NAME: php
    volumes_from:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      PMA_USER: wordpress
      PMA_PASSWORD: wordpress
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
    ports:
     - "8001:80"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "8002:8025"
```

Using Kitematic I get the following error for nginx:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-init.d/wordpress-nginx.sh
nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf:83
```

It seems that the ports are not really set correctly. Comparing the ports for the nginx container on my old computer with the new installation shows that more clearly:

Old Computer:
[image]

New computer:
[image]

Do you have any idea of what I have done wrong or how I can set up the rights ports?

EDIT:

This is the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf`:

```
    server {
        server_name wordpress;
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php;

        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        add_header Cache-Control "store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

        location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
            allow all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            try_files $uri =204;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /readme.html {
            return 404;
        }

        location ~* ^.*(\.(?:git|svn|htaccess|txt|pot?))$ {
            return 404;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.flv$ {
            flv;
        }

        location ~* .*\.(?:m4a|mp4|mov)$ {
            mp4;
            mp4_buffer_size     1M;
            mp4_max_buffer_size 5M;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
            expires max;
            tcp_nodelay off;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

        # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
            }

            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            track_uploads uploads 60s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf` + `/docker-entrypoint-init.d/wordpress-nginx.sh`.

Comment: Where can I find it? I just might be to stupid to find it, but probably you can give me a hint?

Comment: Nobody is stupid, It's one more thing to learn.
Take a look inside your docker. `docker ps` + `docker exec -ti containerName bash` + `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf`

Comment: Haha, thanks, that is good to hear ;) But I guess that I should use the nginx container? It is always stopping to run, I guess due to the error shown above. So I can't use the exec command to log in.

Comment: Maybe you can find your config outside ? Otherwise, try to run your container like : `docker run -ti imageName bash`

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, with that I was able to open it. I attached it as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf` on line 83 where the `fastcgi_pass backend` configuration refers to a `backend` service that doesn't exist.

Looking at the nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass), this configuration requires either the IP address or DNS name of a FastCGI server **AND** a port. IOW, even if you renamed your `php` service in your docker-compose.yml to `backend`, nginx will still fail with another `nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf:83` error, because the port number is missing.

Since this `wordpress.conf` is baked into the `wodby/wordpress-nginx` image, either you have to create your own Dockerfile based on this image, or overwrite its `/etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf` file.

To overwrite the `wordpress.conf` file, obtain a copy of the original from the container, and change the `fastcgi_pass` section to `php:80`:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    return 404;
  }

  include fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass php:80;
  track_uploads uploads 60s;
}
```

Then update the `nginx` service definition in your docker-compose.yaml to use your version of the `wordpress.conf` using `volumes` as seen below.

```
nginx:
  image: wodby/wordpress-nginx
  environment:
    NGINX_SERVER_NAME: nginx
    NGINX_UPSTREAM_NAME: php
  ports:
    - "8000:80"
  depends_on:
    - php
  volumes:
    - ./wordpress.conf:/etc/gotpl/wordpress.conf.tpl
```

Note that the target path in the container is `/etc/gotpl/wordpress.conf.tpl` because that's the source the container's `/docker-entrypoint.sh` script copies from into the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder.

Finally, as pointed out in my original answer, don't forget to change all references of `localhost` in your docker-compose.yaml file to the correct service name.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Try change the `NGINX_SERVER_NAME` environment variable from `localhost` to `nginx`.

When you run your application as a Compose project, Compose sets up a default single [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) for your application. This network is named after your Compose project, which you can view by running the `docker network ls` command. All the containers in your project join that network and are both reachable and discoverable by each other via their hostnames, which are set to be identical to the containers name. You can read more about Docker Compose Networking in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

In your case, `localhost` isn't reachable by other containers in your application.

You will have to make the same change to the `PHP_HOST_NAME` environment variable.

Comment: Hey Ivan, thanks for your answer. I tried your advise, but I was still running into the same problems.

Comment: @sma Just to confirm, so you changed `NGINX_SERVER_NAME` to `nginx` and `PHP_HOST_NAME` to `php:8000`?

Comment: Hey Ivan, I tried it with the combination you mentioned above, and also with other combinations. I still could not connect to the site.

Comment: I _think_ this is the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/wodby/wordpress-nginx/~/dockerfile/) of the `wodby/wordpress-nginx:latest` image. It's hard to tell whether your environment variables are still correct in this version. One thing you can try is to rename your `php` service to `backend`. And yes, always pin the image version, and not rely on `latest`.

Comment: I exported my old images now from the old computer and loaded them at my new computer now. So I have exactly the same images in my new enviroment now. But still, I get the same error. It is really frustrating.

Comment: @sma I have updated my answer, where I overwrite the buggy `wordpress.conf` file with a local copy that contains fixes.

Comment: Hey Ivan, thanks for your answer. I tried to make the changes. So I copied the original wordpress.conf and made the changes. Now I have the local file called `wordpress.conf.tpl`. But I am struggeling with the path in the docker-yaml file. I guess it is exactly what you meant with the `etc/`-path. Is it `etc/<local path>/wordpress.conf.tpl`?

Comment: On your local, the `wordpress.conf` can be located anywhere. Use `./wordpress.conf` if it is in the same folder as your docker-compose.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but like you can see in the error log, the problem is in the line `fastcgi_pass backend;`.

`backend` is not a valid upstream. In your case you should reference the php service (`php` in your `docker-compose` file), and reference it like `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` (I'm assuming the port you are using for the php fpm is 9000, but could be another, in which case you should change accordingly).